# Representations of the symmetric group induced by an embedding

Tags: permutations, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I'm working on a problem where I have an embedding of the form:
$$
K:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^{2^n}:(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\mapsto(1,x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_1x_2,x_1x_3,\cdots,x_1\cdots x_n)
$$
In case that's hard to parse, the new vector can be broken up into pieces of size $_nC_m$, each piece consisting of all the possible products of $m$ elements of the original vector.

Now let $\pi\in S_n$ be a permutation. I'm interested in constructing the representation of $\pi$, $\mathcal D^K_\pi$, so that 
$$
K(\pi{\mathbf x}) =\mathcal D^K_\pi K({\mathbf x}) 
$$

For small $n$, I can construct these matrices tediously by hand, and I hardcode the results. I'd like to know a bit more about the general theory of how to do this for any finite $n$, so that my code could generate these matrices on the fly.

Any comments or reading suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Action of $S_n$ on symmetric tensors" is worth a Google.